# How to loop through a list of dictionary, and print out every key and value pair in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I have an list of dictionary in Ansible config

```
myList
    - name: Bob
      age: 25
    - name: Alice
      age: 18
      address: USA
```

I write code as

```
- name: loop through
  debug: msg ="{{item.key}}:{{item.value}}"
  with_items: "{{ myList }}"
```

I want to print out like

```
msg: "name:Bob age:25 name:Alice age:18 address:USA"
```

How can I loop through this dictionary and get key and value pairs? Because it don't know what is the key. If I change as {{ item.name }}, ansible will work, but I also want to know key

Comment: Usually for something like this, i would define a class and then leverage `__repr__` or `__str__` depending on how much readability you want, since in your example `msg` looks pretty easy to parse, i would leverage *__repr__*

Comment: Thank you, @Fallenreaper. I'm not good at python. can you explain more. What is the   __repr__ or __str__ ?

Comment: There's a typo after `myList` – colon missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to loop through the list and parse every item separately:

```
- debug: msg="{{ item | dictsort | map('join',':') | join(' ') }}"
  with_items: "{{ myList }}"
```

Will print:

```
"msg": "age:25 name:Bob"
"msg": "address:USA age:18 name:Alice"
```

If you want to join everything into one line, use:

```
- debug: msg="{{ myList | map('dictsort') | sum(start=[]) | map('join',':') | join(' ') }}"
```

This will give:

```
"msg": "age:25 name:Bob address:USA age:18 name:Alice"
```

Keep in mind that dicts are not sorted in Python, so you generally can't expect your items to be in the same order as in yaml-file. In my example, they are sorted by key name after dictsort filter.

Comment: Could I keep dictionary order?

Comment: @Walter I'm afraid no.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov if the list had a third "order" field, could you use that to sort the dictionary and then ensure the order in the output?

Comment: @dan_linder not sure what you mean. If you have a list – it's already ordered. If you have a dict – it's unsorted.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov - Thanks, I was overlooking that.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your text:
myList
    - name: Bob
      age: 25
    - name: Alice
      age: 18
      address: USA

Here is the Answer:

> > > text='''myList
> > >           - name: Bob
> > >             age: 25
> > >           - name: Alice
> > >             age: 18
> > >             address: USA'''

```
>>> final_text=''
```

> > > for line in text.split('\n'):
> > >           line1=line.replace(' ','').replace('-','')
> > >           if 'myList' not in line1:
> > >               final_text+=line1+' '
> > >
> > > final_text
> > >       'name:Bob age:25 name:Alice age:18 address:USA '

Comment: Could I have ansible syntax solution?

Answer (score -1):

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, name, age, address):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.address = address

  def __str__(self):
    # String Representation of your Data.
    return "name:%s age:%d address:%s" % (self.name, self.age, self.address)
```

then you can have a list of objects you created.  I am using some sample data here to create a list of dicts.

```
dict={"name":"Hello World", "age":23, "address":"Test address"}
myList = [dict,dict,dict]
objList = []
for row in myList:
  objList.append(str(Person(**row)))

result = ' '.join(objList)
print(result)
```

It ends out printing: **name:Hello World age:23 address:Test address name:Hello World age:23 address:Test address name:Hello World age:23 address:Test address**

I was going to do REPR but that is used a bit more differently, and i thought this might be better suited for your needs.

If you want to keep it really simple you can do this:

```
dict={"name":"Hello World", "age":23, "address":"Test address"}
myList = [dict,dict,dict]
objList = []
for row in myList;
  tmp = []
  for k in row:
    tmp.append("%s:%s" % (k, row[k]))
  objList.append(" ".join(tmp))
print(" ".join(objList))
```

Comment: So in this case, I should create a separate python file to deal with this, Ansible cannot do it without extra custom module. Am I right?

Comment: added another way to do it, with just 2 little loops